# HTTPWebResponse is encrypted unless Fiddler is open

Tags: api, encryption, httpwebrequest, fiddler, httpwebresponse

Same code and 2 different responses for fiddler is open or not. Here is the results I have.

When Fiddler is closed:

```
         "??;\0d?5??t?<???T?\u0010\b?\rA\u0014D@q?Y?m\t[Xu???_?^?Hh?[\u00124J?????nu0???m\u0010?;?????CL#^?:)?{\f?????h?-??;6G\u0019????\u0010????????o\u001f?}???b????\u0014\u0005??????\0\t???}?M??w?s,?D??>????7?fP{\u007f\u001c\u001b????\u0011?P????N????\u0018?W?j\aG??V?????I\u00053%??{F\nE????\u001a??<??1h???K?c2??????????>?y??d?u?????N3????>g^?S\u001by\r)6?V??}Q:\u0016??\u0017??K?wK??????\u001d??jsXI\u0010?g?
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
        E`\u0002=??\u0006??0\u00126\u000f??\u00189|???\u0005???\r?????*\n?\r?DPr5\u0013u????????Vb??? 
       g??\u00150\0\a????????[?a?g??(?lr??\u000e?~B?????\u007f?P`??i?v??????;??{?????0?:??Y???\u001d?;?)d?s????0\?q?e@???#?mR]???G\u001f`\r??1???f??\u0013!?w???\bh???Mg*\t?c?B?6??Z?6???????a?\u001f\u0004???-S?\u001a\u0016?Ue?((???h\u001d?? <????\u0018??\u001bJ??N???c?\u000f?n8L?I/H???s\u0002@\u0011??7"
```

When Fiddler is open :

```
[{"appid":730,"assetid":"2mf1lak","bot_id":5300483,"bundle_id":null,"color":"eb4b4b","contextid":"2","custom_price":8,"icon_url":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1ObcTjxP0966lYOAh_L1Ibfum2pD6sl0g_PE8bP5gVO8v11tZzqhLYGRIw86aQ2G81i3k-bog8XptcjIynFi7CB3sH6Jzh2_1BlFcKUx0ncN5NuB","id":"2mf1lak","img":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1ObcTjxP0966lYOAh_L1Ibfum2pD6sl0g_PE8bP5gVO8v11tZzqhLYGRIw86aQ2G81i3k-bog8XptcjIynFi7CB3sH6Jzh2_1BlFcKUx0ncN5NuB","market_name":"\u2605 Gut Knife | Doppler (Factory New) - Black Pearl","market_value":33548,"name":"\u2605 Gut Knife | Doppler (Factory New) - Black Pearl","name_color":"8650AC","paint_index":417,"tradable":true,"tradelock":false,"type":"\u2605 Covert Knife","wear":null},wmFrFC5xufuhpK5vcuayXYxsyVz4GGdwUJGz70rjQ","market_name":"USP-S | Neo-Noir (Field-Tested)","market_value":2423,"name":"USP-S | Neo-Noir (Field-Tested)","name_color":"D2D2D2","paint_index":null,"tradable":true,"tradelock":false,"type":"Covert Pistol","wear":null} 
.
.
.
]
```

This is how I read response:

```
         HttpWebResponse response = GetResponse();

        var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        string responseText = "";
        using(var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        response.Close();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would guess that the first response is not encrypted but compressed. Check the response headers. How to handle a compressed response see for example here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/jun/29/httpwebrequest-and-gzip-http-responses

Comment: So, fiddler is decompressing it when it's open?

Comment: I would assume so. And for forwarding it to the client application no compression is applied. As I said check the response headers without Fiddler on between. You will most likely find the info there that the content is compressed. Usually a server only sends a compressed response if the client has indicated in the request that compression is supported. Therefore also check the request you are sending.